# how to log testsuite or testcase results in a file using soapui scripting (groovy)?

Tags: logging, groovy, soapui

I need to log TestResults in a text file using SoapUI scripting eg. Groovy script. It will be very helpful if it would be either TestSuite results or a TestCase results. Can anyone please give me script sample for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a variable as below

```
def object1= context.expand( '${object1#Response#declare namespace ns2=\'http://namespace.suha.com\'; //ns2:namespaceResponse[1]/methodname[1]}' )
```

You can create a .txt file and write the variable into this file as below.

```
today = new Date()
sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm")
todayStr = sdf.format(today)
new File( "D:/" + todayStr + "report.txt" ).write(object1, "UTF-8" )
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a forum post discussing how to do it easily.  Shows how to log both the request and/or response.  It worked first try for me, after I tried a lot of other scripts.

http://www.soapui.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=5208